# pip install packages for python 3

Tags: python, pip

I don't know what I have did but now when use `pip` to install a package it install it for python 3 (python3.3 folder) not for python2.7.

Another problem I installed `django_debug_toolbar` and now my django version is 1.6.4 not 1.3 I installed.

Now I can't remove django 1.6.4 with pip. Do you have a solution?

Comment: I want to know why do you downvote me?

Answer (score 1):

Learn using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html). It allows you to have different environments with isolated version of Python and set of installed packages. Each created virtual environment is by default having pip installed.

You messed up things (as you know very well) as you probably reinstalled pip for another version of Python.

You might find more versions of `pip` in your system. Check the version of python they use (on Linux watch the shebang on first line). Use explicit path to proper pip to manage packages for related Python.

Often people install pip and rename it or give an alias - names like `pip33` or `pip27`.

Note, that `virtualenv` allows creation of different environments (with different Python versions) without need to install virutalenv for each of these Pythons.

With `virtualenv` I would also highly recommend using [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which adds a few very handy commands.

Comment: I haven't reinstalled `pip`.

Comment: Then your PATH had to change. When you run `python`, what version does it report? I would guess 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

My problem came when I installed django_debug_toolbar. when I pip-installed django-debug-toolbar, the latest version of Django was installed automatically.